# Sum of sales by Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

How can i use SQL and SUM monthly data (quarter view)? I will not use Stored Procedures etc.

```
Current data:
   ID  |  Sales
201601 |   5
201602 |   15
201603 |   5
201604 |   20
201605 |   8
201606 |   2
```

...

My ID column is like yyyymm

What I want is:

```
Quarter  |  Sales
   Q1    |   25
   Q2    |   30

....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like below

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(ID,4) Year,
  'Q'+ CAST((CAST(RIGHT(ID,2) AS INT)-1 )/3 +1 AS varchar) Quarter,
  SUM(Sales) Sales
FROM 
   Yourtable
GROUP BY 
  LEFT(ID,4), 
  'Q'+ CAST((CAST(RIGHT(ID,2) AS INT) -1 )/3 +1 AS varchar) 
order by year
```

**[SQL demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b5ba/6)**

Comment: Thank you. Please check the example SQL [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b5ba/1) the calculation is not correct. Do you know why?

Comment: Answer updated! Thank you for pointing our fallacy in calculations. See updated link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b5ba/6

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEPART` and `QUARTER` to get the quarter of a `DATETIME`.  You just need to build the `DATETIME` using `DATEFROMPARTS` and parsing your ID column.

The `CONCAT` just adds 'Q' to the period number.

```
SELECT  LEFT(id,4) [Year], 
        CONCAT('Q',DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(id,4), RIGHT(id, 2), 1))) [Quarter],
        SUM(Sales) [Sales]
FROM    yourtable
GROUP BY LEFT(id,4), DATEPART(q, DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(id,4), RIGHT(id, 2), 1))
ORDER BY [Year], [Quarter]
```

Comment: Currently the calculation is over all years. Example [SQL] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b5ba/3) how can i modify this to get only the quartar for each year?

Comment: by adding the year `LEFT(ID,4)` to your select and group by. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b5ba/9